# get-aduser -ldapfilter this or that

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a function so that I can more quickly lookup somebody's phone number or reverse lookup an extension.

So far I have this saved as a ps1 file:

```
$find=$args[0]
Get-ADUser -properties * -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname*$find*)" | ft samaccountname,Name,telephone number
Get-ADUser -properties * -LDAPFilter "(telephonenumber=555 555-*$find*)" | ft samaccountname,Name,telephonenumber
```

The code works, but obviously I get red error code for either the first or second condition every time.  I've tried `(|(This)(That))`, I've tried `-erroraction silentlycontinue`, I've tried `-LDAPFilter (This) -OR (That)`.

What I'm ultimately after is a function I can add to my profile, so that I can type either:

```
lookup ABC
lookup 2948
```

and it will do a forward lookup or a reverse lookup.  It can be a loose search and return a few too many results if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-read your question and edited. This will work for you, you can add your formatting and returned properties as you see fit.

```
function lookup {
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
[string]$search
)

    if ($search -match '[a-z][A-Z]'){
        return (Get-ADUser $search -Properties TelephoneNumber).TelePhoneNumber
    }

    if ($search -match '[0-9]'){
        return Get-ADUser -Properties TelephoneNumber -Filter "TelephoneNumber -like '*$search*'"
    }

}
```

Comment: This is great!  I modified it to add a final `| select Name` on the second statement so that only the name is returned.  Thanks so much Chris!

Comment: @davehahn no problem. If you have any weird characters in your domain that also have numbers and if it throws a username search into the telephone logic, just add " -and $search -notmatch '[a-z][A-Z]'" to the second logic gate. You shouldn't need it, but just in case.

Answer (score 0):

`(|(firstClause)(secondClause))` is the correct syntax for `OR` filters in LDAP - that's not your problem.

Both filter clauses contain syntactical errors.
The first one should be (notice the `=`):

```
(samaccountname=*$find*)
```

The second one is invalid because only leading or trailing `*` is permitted. You could do:

```
(telephonenumber=*$find*)
```

and then use `Where-Object` to narrow the results to numbers with the proper prefix:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties telephonenumber -LDAPFilter "(|(samaccountname*$find*)(telephonenumber=*$find*))" |Where-Object { $_.telephoneNumber -like "555 555-*"}
```

---

Be aware that leading `*` are horribly slow due to the way these values are looked up internally in Active Directory.

Comment: Also the use `-Properties *` should be discouraged for performance reasons. Like you need _all_ the properties. He is only using the `telephonenumber` so `-Properties telephonenumber`

Comment: @Matt true, not as bad if the filter is narrow enough though (`-Filter * -Properties *` would be horrible)

Comment: If anyone is going to use LDAPFilter, you might as well just use ADSI.. lol!

Comment: @ChrisKuperstein Sorry but that's complete BS. `-Filter` gets translated to an LDAP filter internally

Comment: The reason why I say you might as well use ADSI if you're going to use LDAPFilter is because if you're taking the time to type out that long of a filter, you might as well be using ADSI. Didn't say it from a functionality standpoint. It was just a joke.

Comment: meh. It's a trade-off - simplicity in syntax vs. control/flexibility. If you want to construct complex filters with multple OR clauses for example, LDAP filter syntax is definitely your friend

Answer (score 0):

I would probably specify two parameters and two separate parameter sets. Example:

```
# Get-User.ps1
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="SamAccountName")]
param(
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName="SamAccountName",Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $SamAccountName,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName="TelephoneNumber",Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $TelephoneNumber
)

$params = @{
  "Properties" = "*"
  "LDAPFilter" = ""
}
switch ( $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName ) {
  "SamAccountName" {
    $params.LDAPFilter = "(sAMAccountName=$SamAccountName)"
  }
  "TelephoneNumber" {
    $params.LDAPFilter = "(telephoneNumber=$TelephoneNumber)"
  }
}
Get-ADUser @params
```

With this you could write:

```
Get-User thisusername
```

or

```
Get-User -TelephoneNumber thisphonenumber
```

I would caution against using `-Properties "*"` as this will be quite slow. Better to specify the list of attributes you want to see.